# Need to identify correct searchVIew Listener method for button to prepare to close searchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, listener, searchview, oncreate

Need to get the right searchView Listener method to place my code to change my erase typed up search result (round X) button to become a close the searchView entirely white (X) button.

Here's my code to create searchView in action bar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

 MenuItem item =menu.findItem(menuSearch);
    final  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
```

In the 1st picture when I tap on the Search Icon, the following pops up and my code for it:

```
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

     ImageView searchClose = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);

        }
    });
```

[image]

So you can click on the (X) above and just close the searchView. Or you can start typing on the keyboard to search and you get the following: Notice now the (X) turned into a (round X) which means to delete what you're typing in keyboard.

[image]

Here's the code for above:

```
       @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            ImageView searchCancel = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchCancel.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp);


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now, if I click that (round X) again, I need it to go back to the original white (X) to be able to close the searchView Completely. So i'd need to use the first code with R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp again.

It doesn't work on the following methods:

```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener
   searchView.setOnCloseListener
```

I know the right code, I'm just missing the right searchView Listener method. Which Listener method do I use to turn that (round X) back to white (X) when the (round X) is clicked on.

(I hope I explained it thoroughly, if not, I'd like my searchView to work like in Snapchat, you'll see it uses 2 different X's, one to delete what user typed, one to close the searchView completely).

### So I just need the correct Listener method to use not the code that goes inside the method.

Comment: `onQueryTextChange()` is called when input is cancelled with a zero-length string. Are you not seeing that in your code?

Comment: All I see in my code is onQueryTextChange() is only called when you tap on the keyboard. I need a code that would call me tapping on the round X or a code that would call before closing searchView.

Comment: In my code, `onQueryTextChange()` is called with a zero-length string when 1) something is already entered into the search field and 2) the "X" is tapped. If you are not seeing that same sequence, check to make sure that you aren't otherwise intercepting the touch.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by zero-length string. Do I have to make an if/else statement in OnQueryTextChange()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onQueryTextChange()` is called when input is cancelled with a zero-length string. In essence, you want to show one type of "X" is the length is zero-length, otherwise, another type.  Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    ImageView searchCancel =
            searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCancel.setImageResource(
            (newText.length() > 0)
            ? R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp:
            : R.drawable.[the other type of "X"]);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you're correct, it does work your way. I thought I'd need to use a different method (which I couldn't find).